# Conditionally assert element values in DOM depending on it's value in backend with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

**Trying to do Cypress Testing with my React app.**

I'm retrieving an object with an attribute *expirationDate* from the backend. It's an integer with format *YYYYMMDD*. In my corresponding frontend in the `<input>` component, it's rendered as an *YYYY-MM-DD* string.

However the object may optionally not have an expiration date at all, which is instead represented as the attribute being *-1* or *-2*. This is presented as an empty string '' in the `<input>`.

I thus need to conditionally check the value. How do I go about doing this with Cypress?

Closest I have right now is

```
cy.get('#input-expiration-date').should('have.value', expirationDate || '')
```

But this is not really an accurate test of the above conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Conditional testing can be done as follows, but this is **bad practice**.

```js
cy.get('#input-expiration-date')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(val => {
    
    if (val === expirationDate) {     // fails because page is still fetching
      ...
    }
  })
```

The test runs faster than the value can be fetched from the server.

You can avoid the issue by waiting for the object fetch with `cy.intercept()` and do the conditional check then.

```js
let expirationDate = 'YYYYMMDD'

cy.intercept(url).as('object')

cy.visit(...)

cy.wait('@object').then(object => {

  if (object.expirationDate) {
    cy.get('#input-expiration-date')
      .should('have.value', expirationDate)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There a Chai method [oneOf()](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) you can use.

Cypress uses Chai internally, so the expression works inside `.should()`.

```js
cy.get('#input-expiration-date')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('have.oneOf', [expirationDate, ''])
```

Using Chai directly

```js
cy.get('#input-expiration-date').then($input => {
  expect($input.val()).to.have.oneOf([expirationDate, ''])
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `cy.intercept()` to get the value coming from the back-end.

General approach (may vary depending on response pattern):

```js
cy.intercept('some-api-request').as('api')

// trigger the backend request/response
cy.get('button').click()


cy.wait('api').then(interception => {

  const obj = interception.response.body;     // extract object
  const expirationDate  = obj.expirationDate  // and it's expirationDate 
  const hasNoExpiration = expirationDate === -1 && expirationDate === -2

  cont expectedValue = hasNoExpiration ? '' : 
    `${expirationDate.slice(0,4)}-${expirationDate.slice(4,2)}-${expirationDate.slice(6,2)}`

  cy.get('#input-expiration-date').should('have.value', expectedValue)

})
```

You can also go one step further and **eliminate any backend variation** by stubbing

```js
cy.intercept('some-api-request', {body: { expirationDate: -1 }).as('api')

// trigger the backend request/response
cy.get('button').click()

cy.wait('api')
cy.get('#input-expiration-date').should('have.value', '')
```

```js
cy.intercept('some-api-request', {body: { expirationDate: '20220319' }).as('api')

// trigger the backend request/response
cy.get('button').click()

cy.wait('api')
cy.get('#input-expiration-date').should('have.value', '2022-03-19')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```js
cy.get('#input-expiration-date').then(element => {
//and here you can have conditions and access the DOM element

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to check and further do some actions based on the value, you can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('#input-expiration-date')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    if (val == expirationDate) {
      //Do something
    } else if (val == '') {
      // Do something
    } else {
      //Do something
    }
  })
```